# Javascript update for loop value after delete

Tags: javascript

First, [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL4ota4v/11/)

I have dynamically created content that is supposed to delete when they are clicked. I am using the variable `emma` to create a click function for each div that is clicked.

Every time I click on a `content` div, the amount of `content`s is reduced. As such, I want my `emma` count to reduce corresponding to its place in the DOM.

So if I click on `Content 1`, whose `emma` value in the loop is `1`, `Content 1` deletes, and in its place is `Content 2`. I want `Content 2` to take its place and have an `emma` value of `1`. Instead, if I click on `Content 2` after deleting `Content 1`, then the value of `emma` on `Content 2` is still `2`.

I am ultimately using the `emma` variable for CRUD features.

How might I adjust to keep my `emma` value updated after each of my `content` is deleted?

```
function digiteditcall(){
    for (emma = 0; emma < mar; emma++){
        (function(emma){
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                let tenille = "content"+emma;
                if ( (e.target && e.target.id == tenille) || (e.target && e.target.parentNode.id == tenille) ){
                    maincontainer.removeChild(document.getElementById(tenille));
                    mar--;
                    console.log(emma);
                }
            });
        })(emma);
    }
}
```

Again, here is [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL4ota4v/11/)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use any library? using jQuery you can do that in very few lines.

Comment: Define the emma variable with `let` and you don't need the closure. This is an archaic pattern - `let` was added to the spec so you don't have to do this anymore.... that said, I really don't know what you mean by "keep the emma variable updated"...

Comment: Instead of the links to fiddles you can put it directly in using the edit button (CTRL-M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it looks like you might be over complicating things.

Take a look at this and see if it does what you are expecting.

EDIT: I added the Emma value as a custom data attribute to the element. So you can see it on the DOM as `data-emma="X"` or with JavaScript via `el.dataset.emma`

```js
(function cobrakai() {
  let bar = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    bar += "<p id='content" + i + "' class='content' data-emma='" + i + "'>Content " + i + "</p>";
  }
  maincontainer.innerHTML += bar;
})();

maincontainer.addEventListener('click', reDo);

function reDo(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'P') return;
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var nextElIndex = false;
  document.querySelectorAll('#maincontainer p').forEach((el, i) => {
    if(e.target.id == el.id) {
     el.remove();
      nextElIndex = i;      
    }else if(nextElIndex !== false){
       el.id = 'content'+ nextElIndex;
       el.textContent = 'Content '+ nextElIndex;
       el.dataset.emma = nextElIndex;
       nextElIndex++;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontainer"></div>
```

Comment: this was the right idea. for each instead of a bunch of for loops.

Comment: Awesome. glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `jQuery`(which is less headache), try this:

```
 $document.ready(function(){
 $("#maincontainer").click(function(){
 $("#maincontainer").hide();
 })
})
```

otherwise use ES6 `let` keyword for your `emma` which provides block-level scope.

Comment: yes. i decided to make an app using just vanilla javascript. never again.